# Location isn't readable when picking csv document with expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I have an application where I want to load a CSV into the app's memory. I'm using expo and `expo-document-picker`. It is returning OK the object with the cached file address, however when I read using expo-file-system it gives an error. Here's the code snippet.

```js
            let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
                type: 'text/comma-separated-values',
                copyToCacheDirectory: true,
                multiple: false,
            });
            
            console.log(result);
            // Console.log
            // > {"mimeType": "text/comma-separated-values", "name": "financas.CSV", "size": 592, "type": "success", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/DocumentPicker/d37cb00e-4ab4-4b79-9650-0aac15f8a92c.CSV"}

            if (result.type === 'success') {
                let fileContent = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(result.uri, { encoding: 'utf8' });
                // Console.log
                // [Error: Location 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/DocumentPicker/d37cb00e-4ab4-4b79-9650-0aac15f8a92c.CSV' isn't readable.]
                console.log(fileContent);
```

Using SDK48 expo and all latest libs.

read csv file as string

Comment: Please add more information about the error to the question

Comment: Yep, having the same problem, looks like it's something new!